# How to remove excess td cell in foreach condition

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

How can I remove excess td cell like on the image, the rowspan for Price Vat Inc. and Total is based on count, count is based on # of productid, as you can see on the given code.

[This is my Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evkxE.jpg)

this is my PHP code:

```
$quoteproducts = $this->pmis->get_Squoteproducts1($projectquoteid,'consumables');
$q1 = $this->pmis->get_Squoteproducts2($projectquoteid,'consumables');
//var_dump($q1[0]['cnt']);
$cnt = $q1[0]['cnt'];
$total=0;
$ctr = 1;
$last_key = '';
if($quoteproducts){
    foreach($quoteproducts as $q){
        $current_key = 0;
        $subtotal = $q['price'] * $q['qty'];
        //echo $q['stock'];
        $strval .='
        <tr>
        <td align="center">'.$ctr.'</td>
        <td  class="d1">'.$q['productname'].'</td>

        <td align="center" class="d1">'.$q['qty'].'</td>
        <td align="center" class="d1">'.$q['unit'].'</td>


        <td align="center" rowspan="'.$cnt.'"></td>
        <td align="center" rowspan="'.$cnt.'"></td>

        </tr>
        ';
        $ctr ++;
        $total = $subtotal + $total;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Post useful view file sections, we can't mind read how you are setting up the rest of the table that isn't visible here... Also what is $cnt returning...

Comment: $q1 = $this->pmis->get_Squoteproducts2($projectquoteid,'consumables');
$cnt = $q1[0]['cnt'];

$cnt = stand for # of productid detected, same as counter

Thank you

Comment: I don't mean to be condescending, but I can see all that same information in the code above. What does "# of productid detected" mean? What does the function actually return (an example).... Further, you need to include your view for the rest of the table, again, not a mind reader. Troubleshooting requires information, and thus far you haven't given enough to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: As you can see on my screenshot, i just want to remove the excess td. Thank you

Comment: Yea, again; how can we do that without seeing how you are constructing the rest of your table? What does an example of the returned code from $cnt look like as this may very well contribute to your problem? This is basic stuff most *good* questions have on the site which is why your question is downvoted. You will not receive help until you provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rowspan from table. It is due to using rowspan.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. I understand you are new here, but providing more details about your question will help the community to help you better. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and see if you can improve your question in any way. For starters, add tags to specify to which specific technology your question belongs. Good luck!

Comment: @pragya it must be there for some reason, but he's not telling me why ;)